# Redirecting site is not working? help

Tags: https

ubuntu 14.04 and Server version: Apache/2.4.16 (Ubuntu)

The redirect rule is not working or am i missing something ? when i type in the browser, i want to use https:teampass.domain.org  but instead https://teampass.domain.org/teampass  is the only url that works. Am i missiong something? how can i get to use https://teampass.domain.org

more /etc/hosts

```
 127.0.0.1       localhost
 127.0.1.1       teampass
 192.*.*.*   teampass       teampass.domain.org

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
 ::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
 ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

More /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
  ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

 Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

 PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

 Timeout 300


  KeepAlive On

  MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

  KeepAliveTimeout 15


# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
 User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
 Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

  HostnameLookups Off

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log


   LogLevel warn

 # Include module configuration:
 IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load

 IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

  # Include list of ports to listen on
  Include ports.conf


    <Directory />

    Options FollowSymLinks

    AllowOverride None

    Require all denied

   </Directory>


  <Directory /usr/share>

    AllowOverride None

    Require all granted

   </Directory>

   <Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride ALL
    Require all granted
   </Directory>

   <Directory /srv/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
     </Directory>


  AccessFileName .htaccess


  <FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
   </FilesMatch>



 # Include generic snippets of statements
 IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

  # Include the virtual host configurations:
   IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet

# phpMyAdmin Configuration
 Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf

 #load ssl module
 #LoadModule ssl_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so
```

more /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf

```
 <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName teampass.domain.org
    Serveralias www.teampass.domain.org
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    SSLEngine on

    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/DigiCertCA
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/star_domain_org
    SSLCertificateKeyfile /etc/apache2/ssl/teampass.key
</VirtualHost>
```

more /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/teampass.conf

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName teampass
  Redirect permanent /  https://teampass.domain.org/

  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  ServerAlias www.teampass.domain.org
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/teampass
  <Directory /var/www/html>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            # DO NOT REMOVE
            RewriteOptions Inherit
    </IfModule>
   </VirtualHost>


   <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName teampass.
    #ServerAlias www.teampass.domain.org
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/teampass

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/star_domain_org
    SSLCertificateKeyfile /etc/apache2/ssl/teampass.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/DigiCertCA
    SSLEngine on
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/teampass_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/teampass_access.log combined

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            # DO NOT REMOVE
           RewriteOptions Inherit
    </IfModule>
    </VirtualHost>
```

responding to .htaccess

opt is where the mail teampass package is stored. /var/www/html has the link

teampass in html

root@teampass:~# find / -name .htaccess

```
 /opt/TeamPass-2.1.23/includes/avatars/.htaccess

 /opt/TeamPass-2.1.23/upload/.htaccess
```

more /opt/TeamPass-2.1.23/includes/avatars/.htaccess

```
 AddHandler cgi-script .php .php3 .php4 .phtml .pl .py .jsp .asp .htm .shtml     
 .sh .cgi

 Options -ExecCGI
```

more /opt/TeamPass-2.1.23/upload/.htaccess

```
AddHandler cgi-script .php .php3 .php4 .phtml .pl .py .jsp .asp .htm .shtml       

  .sh .cgi

 Options -ExecCGI

 RewriteEngine On
```

Comment: Your edits to `/etc/hosts` only affect the local machine, and not requests from other hosts.  Are you sure you're doing what you think you're doing?

Comment: @DopeGhoti I put the ip of the localhost to resolve teampass.

Comment: Do you want the actual content to be presented as https://teampass.domain.org/ or as https://teampass.domain.org/teampass/ ?

Comment: as teampass.domain.org

Answer (score 0):

In your `teampass.conf` file change the `DocumentRoot` line to read

`DocumentRoot /var/www/html/teampass/teampass`

for both virtual hosts

Comment: thanks for the help but teampass is on html so DocumentRoot should be /var/www/html/  or /var/www/html/teampass

Comment: If the actual html files are located in `/var/www/html/teampass` and you still have to use https://teampass.domain.com/teampass to access them then you must have another rewrite rule somewhere that we're not seeing.  Otherwise the content would be available at https://teampass.domain.com/.  Are there any `.htaccess` files in the teampass directory?

Comment: re-edited the file above to respond to your comment.

Comment: How does `/opt` get pulled into this?

Comment: /opt hold the actual teampass package. html in /var/www holds a symbolik link called teampass.